# What is the equivalent to MenuItemSource in WinUI 3 NavigationView

Tags: xaml, winui-3, navigationview

I'm trying to bind to the `NavigationView` using the `MenuItemSource` property, but apparently, that property has gone away in WinUI 3. I searched the documentation, but it seems to only go to 2.8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview?view=winui-2.8

My navigation view looks like this.

```
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                     Loaded="NavView_Loaded"
                     ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked"
                     BackRequested="NavView_BackRequested"
                     Grid.Column="0"                         
                     MenuItemSource = "{x:Bind Categories, Mode=OneWay}"> 
                    
        <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
            <!-- See AutoSuggestBox documentation for
             more info about how to implement search. -->
            <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="NavViewSearchBox" QueryIcon="Find"/>
        </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Padding="12,0,12,24" IsTabStop="True"
               NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </NavigationView>
```

The MenuItemSource throws:

> The property 'MenuItemSource' was not found in type 'NavigationView'

How can I bind an `ObservableCollection` to the `NavigationView` in WinUi 3?

Comment: Have you seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.menuitemssource MenuItemsSource is now a property on NavigationViewItem

Comment: Thank you. It is now with an 's.' The link is helpful.

Comment: Does the code you posted actually work? From what I can see, the property has always been named with an s.

Comment: Because of the low amount of WinUI 3 examples, I borrowed from WPF or UWP, and as I recall it was MenuItemSource. I'm a little away from it now, but that's what I recall.